# Specific parametrization of a sphere

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, parametrization

I would like to parametrize the region
\begin{equation}
M=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \text{ with } z \leq x+y \} 
\end{equation}
and calculate the flux $\iint_S F\cdot n \ dS$ where $S=\partial M$. The problem is'nt the flux but this parametrization. With spherical coordinates i know how to write the sphere, but the inequality
\begin{equation}
z\leq x+y
\end{equation}
stays
\begin{equation}
\cos(\varphi)\leq\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)
\end{equation}
and im stucked at this part. My geometric intuition tells me that $\theta$ is dependent of $\varphi$, but  how write this? Probably in the flux part we are going to use divergence theorem, because the surface is an sphere with lid $z=x+y$, so we need a parametrization here in order to write $\iiint_M div(F) \ dV$, right?

Comment: The set $\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \text{ and } z \leq x+y \}$ is not a surface. In your own answer you call it $M$. The boundary $S$ (in your own answer) is a surface. I suggest you correct the text accordingly

Comment: Yes, the nomenclature of the question is strange, I copied it in the same way as in the book, I apologize. The surface in the case is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ with$ z \leq x + y$ closed by the disk $D^2$ in the plane $z = x + y$. So $M$ would be the interior delimited by this closed surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an insight: my vector field is $F=(-2xy,y^2,3z)$, so $div(F)=3$. Divergence theorem yields
\begin{equation}
\iint_S F \cdot n \ dS=\iiint_M div(F)\ dV=3\iiint_M dV.
\end{equation}
But the plane $z=x+y$ divides the sphere in two equal parts, hence
\begin{equation}
3\iiint_M dV=3\dfrac{Vol(B_1(0))}{2}=2\pi.
\end{equation}

The result is ok, but the main problem of parametrization remains. I remember seeing somewhere the question of whether or not there is a parameterization for a given surface, does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: Good answer. Basically your $S$ is half of  $S^2$ together with the disk  $D^2$ . The easiest thing would be to split the surface integral in 2 parts

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the last thing on this problem would be to find a parametrization of this region/surface and calculate the flux in those two parts. Then Im gonna show to my students, because i am monitoring an calculus class.

Comment: The boundary (hemisphere+disk) is not smooth. I doubt you can find a smooth parametrizazion. What's the problem in splitting the integral?

Answer (score 0):

Your parametrization is fine. The bounds would be

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\cot^{-1}\left(\sin\theta+\cos\theta\right)}^{\pi}F\cdot n d\varphi d\theta$$

Doing it the other way would split the integral in two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Plotting on mathematica the following code:

$\textit{ParametricPlot3D}$ $[\{\cos[u]\sin[v],\sin[u]sin[v],\cos[v]\},\{u,0,2\pi\},\{v,\cot^{-1}[\cos[u]+\sin[u]],\pi\}] $

the program returned the whole sphere. Even if the bounds make sense, can the computer plot it?

Comment: The surface area element is not $d\varphi d\theta$. It is $sin \varphi d\varphi d\theta$ where $\varphi$ is the colatitude